# How I signalize that a service of OpenRC should start on the hotplugged runlevel?

Tags: udev, openrc

I have a service called `xboxdrvd` that is triggered (and only activated/deactivated) by a [`udev`](https://github.com/ryukinix/xboxdrv-bin/blob/master/61-twin-joystick.rules) rule, however always calling `rc-status` I got that the service was started  on "manual" runlevel:

[image: rc-status]

The hotplugged is not for that type of events? I did read the [gentoo docs](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/OpenRC#Hotplug), but there is not so much thing on there.

Comment: Please post the output of cat /etc/rc.conf | grep "rc_hotplug="

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For OpenRC to display a service as being hotplugged, `IN_HOTPLUG=1` must be in the environment when the service is being started, like so:

```
IN_HOTPLUG=1 /etc/init.d/myservice start
```

Source: I looked at OpenRC’s code to figure this out for a project of mine; this is the relevant line: https://github.com/OpenRC/openrc/blob/301161a7a4bda27c7ebd54c537dfec0cbc926365/src/rc/openrc-run.c#L610